# Drupal - How can I change the default image node settings?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I'm using Drupal 6, Image and NodeAsBlock, and I'm trying to link my nodes into pages. That all works, but each time I link an image I get by default:

- Title
- Thumbnail image size
- No hooks to help me style it in css

Is there a way I can get around this? I really want to just upload an image, click the "create block" textbox and then get fullsize image block created with none of the other crap.

Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find out what template is behind it (using the theme developer module) and then create your own version of that without the extra bits.

Comment: Thanks - I've decided not to go down this route, i'm using views and HTML input instead.

Comment: Much as I like being the accepted answer, for prosperity (ie other people asking the same question in future) it may be better to write your own saying how you did this and accept that answer.